# Halloweenish cartoon where children chase one of their kidnapped friends, trying to rescue him before he changes/dies forever

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

One Saturday morning when I was rather young, perhaps around 2005, I caught part of a strange and singularly melancholy cartoon on broadcast television. This was shown in the US, in English, on non-cable television, and there wasn't any pretensions to its being famous or popular. It was something which was simply "on". I tuned in in the middle of the program, and didn't get to see it all the way to the end.

The contents which I can remember focused upon a group of children who were desperately pursuing one of their number who had been kidnapped or seduced away by something dark; this may have been a character, like a witch, or something more like a concept (ie; "the darkness").

The friends were chasing after him, in the sense of a "Carmen Sandiego" style chase; it seemed they never saw the boy, but only traced him through places he had been but already left.

There was a singular sense of urgency and even mournfulness to this chase, because the friends (and the boy) all understood that if they didn't hurry and save the boy soon, something would change in/about him that would be irreversible, and he would be lost forever.

It's possible in this capacity that the boy was not merely physically taken, but perhaps primarily  it was his soul or spirit that had been pulled away (leaving behind, however, no body).

There was a very Halloween-esque feel to the program, and in tone it possessed a great deal of mournfulness and resignation, rather than adventure or optimism.

The only practical scenes I remember included the friends racing through a large, cavernous, but ultimately empty cathedral: something like Notre Dame. There may have been a section where they were on the roof. There may also have been a spiraling well of some ethereal and magic energy, in a dark alcove. And perhaps a gargoyle or a skeleton in armor?

I believe, also, that there was a segment wherein the kidnapped boy was shown, and something did change about him. Perhaps his head turned into a pumpkin? This was either the actual change occurring, a bit, or else some kind of premonition of what *would* happen to him.

All in all, I rather suspected that the boy would *not* be saved, in the end. And perhaps even at the time, this felt like a program dealing with the idea of loss: something like the lost friend being already dead, and the whole adventure to "save" him ultimately being about coming to terms with that.

This memory visits me every so often. I begin to wonder if I dreamt it. Would anyone know anything about it?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[The Halloween Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Halloween_Tree_(film))*, a cartoon adaptation of [the Ray Bradbury book of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Halloween_Tree).

> The narrator (Ray Bradbury) describes one small American town's preparations for Halloween night. Four friends are shown at their respective homes donning costumes excitedly: Jenny as a witch; Ralph as a mummy; Wally as a monster; and Tom Skelton as a skeleton. They plan to meet up with their best friend, Joe Pipkin, but he doesn't appear. They go to Pip's house and see him being loaded into an ambulance with his parents riding along with him. He has written them a note explaining that he is going to the hospital for an emergency appendectomy and that they should celebrate without him. They feel they cannot start Halloween without him, so they follow the ambulance to visit him at the hospital. Tom suggests a shortcut through the spooky woods: the dark and eerie ravine. They see what looks like a translucent Pip running along the ravine trail, and Tom leads them on, convinced that Pip has designed an elaborate hoax for them. The group races after Pip, who disappears near a towering and darkened mansion.
>
> A man named Carapace Clavicle Moundshroud greets them inside. Moundshroud expresses disappointment that none of the children know what their costumes symbolize. He reveals that he is after the ghost of Pip. Pip seeks and steals a pumpkin with his face carved into it from Moundshroud's Halloween Tree of jack-o'-lanterns. Tom begs Moundshroud to let them come with him and help bring back Pip. Moundshroud initially refuses but relents: if they can keep up with him before dawn, then they might be able to retrieve the pumpkin and get Pip back, while also going on a scavenger hunt of sorts to learn about the significance of their costumes and the origins of Halloween. They begin their pursuit of Pip, traveling back in time by ripping down old circus posters from a nearby barn and crafting a giant October Kite, with the children hanging on as a weighted tail. Moundshroud then takes the four friends to four different places in four different periods in time that coincide with their respective costumes.

### Trailer

I read the book for school as a child, so the plot was familiar enough to recognize. I haven't actually watched the film, but I was aware of its existence.

Comment: As a side note, I only learned while researching this answer that the book started as a screenplay for a Hanna-Barbera animated feature.

Comment: This is incontrovertibly the program I saw. There's something very soothing about finding it after so long. I guess I didn't dream it, after all.. It is strange that so little, maybe 15 minutes of it, could have left such an imprint on me. Thank you for identifying it for me.

Comment: @guest: The book was definitely a bit of a fever dream, I remember. Congrats on finding your book! I hope you stick around.